# TSQL - Get latest rows which their title is not null

Tags: t-sql

I have following table:

```
========================
Id     SubCode    Title
========================
 1        1       test1
 1        2       test2
 1        3       NULL
 1        4       NULL
 2        1        k1
 2        2        k2
 2        3        k3
 2        4       NULL
```

No I want to select latest rows which their title is not `null`, for example for Id `1` then query must show `test2` and for Id `2` it must be `k3`:

```
========================
Id     SubCode    Title
========================
 1        2       test2
 2        3        k3
```

I have written this query:

```
select t.Id, t.SubCode, t.Title from Test t
inner join (
    select max(Id) as Id, max(SubCode) as SubCode
    from Test
    group by Id
) tm on t.Id = tm.Id and t.SubCode = tm.SubCode
```

But this code gives the wrong result:

```
========================
Id     SubCode    Title
========================
 1       4        NULL
 2       4        NULL
```

Any idea?

Comment: So `SubCode` determines how old a record is?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, both `Id` and `SubCode` are keys

Comment: I haven't asked for the keys, i have asked how you determine which record is "older" because you "want to select latest rows"? You should use a `datetime`-column-

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry. Unfortunately  this table doesn't have a date time column but the order is based on inserting them on the table.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi The order of which rows are inserted into a table is not guaranteed to be the order in which queries return the rows. All queries are considered unordered unless `Order by` is specified.

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi: There is no such thing as an insertion order in a table. Table data is by definition unordered. There is no way to access the latest inserted record, when there is no column indicating this (a timestamp or a sequence). So that the latest records have the maximum subcodes in your table is just coincidence? They could just as well have the minimum subcodes or any other? Then you have no means to access the latest records.

Comment: Sorry guys, Yes the order is based on `Sub code`.

Comment: Okay then, I've undeleted my answer, because with this statement it happens to be correct :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to *exclude* NULLs by writing an appropriate `WHERE` clause (`where title is not null`).

However such problems (to get a best / last / ... record) are usually best solved with analytic functions (`RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, `ROW_NUMBER`) anyway, because with them you access the table only once:

```
select id, subcode, title
from
(
  select id, subcode, title, rank() over (partition by id order by subcode desc) as rn
  from test
  where title is not null
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `Title is not null` where clause in your inner select:

```
select t.Id, t.SubCode, t.Title from Test t
inner join (
    select max(Id) as Id, max(SubCode) as SubCode
    from Test
    where Title is not null
    group by Id
) tm on t.Id = tm.Id and t.SubCode = tm.SubCode
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't consider the `where clause`  :)) by the way thanks